# For an AND Gate to work, do the two inputs need to arrive at the same time?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I understand that AND gates require the two inputs to be present for the output to be produced. However, if one input arrives faster than the other input does the output get produced? Additionally, is there such thing as a time delay AND gate?

Thanks

Comment: Whilst waiting for a logic 0 to 1 transition on the late input, the output will remain at zero and change to logic 1 a little after the late signal arrives.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as though you think the AND gate might be edge-triggered. It's not. It's purely combinational logic and the timing is irrelevant.

```
A B  Z
0 0  0
0 1  0
1 0  0
1 1  1
```

*Table 1. The AND truth table has no timing considerations.*

Answer (score 2):

A typical simple logic gate is continuously operating. It's output follows its input(s) in real time, and there are always inputs. Even if the input pins are unconnected the gate will still try to interpret them as logic values.

If one input happens to change before another, the gate will simply continue to do its job and produce whatever output corresponds to the inputs as they are.
If another input later changes - same story.

The gate is not 'triggered' to suddenly perform an operation on its input(s) if or when one or more of them change - it's *always* working.

Answer (score 0):

**Combinational logic:** AND, OR, NOT, MUX etc work continuously and do not "wait" for a signal. If signals arrive too close in time, the theoretical momentary change (if applicable) that you see on a simulator will be filtered due to real-world capacitances. Combinational logic does not remember state as it lacks memory to do so.

**Sequential logic:** Flip-flops and latches have memory and can remember state. The state can change only when clock makes a transition (either +ve edge or -ve edge). If the clock signal is periodic, it is a synchronous circuit, else it is an asynchronous circuit. Level-triggered systems can also be built but are much less common.

The reason I wrote the "Sequential logic" part above is that digital signals can change during the cycle but must remain stable near clock transitions (at least in a good design).

> is there such thing as a time delay AND gate?

Think about it: Such a gate would accept a signal, store it somewhere for a while, process and release it after a delay. But the combinational circuit does not have memory to implement any storage. Hence the name 'combinational'.

Now in real circuits, there are tiny capacitances that can store charge and would delay the input signals from effecting a change at the output. Such a delay is called *propagational delay* and it imposes an upper limit on the usable frequency of the gate. Also the propagational delay from different input pins of any gate to the output pin is just a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Logic levels are just a convenient way we humans use to represent voltage. But really, chips don't care and there is no logic level on that wire, only voltage. So, by convention, we represent that as three logic levels:

- voltage below Vil, that the gate is guaranteed to interpret as 0
- voltage above Vih, that the gate is guaranteed to interpret as 1
- voltage between Vil and Vih, for which there is no guarantee, so we label it "X"

The above isn't physics, it's more like a contract between you (who buy and use the chip) and the chip manuacturer, who guarantees that the chip will read these voltages as 0 or 1, in the allowed temperature range, supply voltage, etc.

When the input voltage is neither a clear 0 or 1 but in the "X" range, the chip can process it as the closest logic level (ie, it kinda works but not guaranteed) but if it's close to the middle of the transition zone, the transistors in the chip will no longer be fully on or off, they'll be in between, so you'll get some undefined voltage at the output.

Obviously, when the input signal transitions from 0 to 1 or the other way around, it will go through the "X" zone, which means during the transition the output level is undefined.

On a simple gate like a NOT gate, that doesn't matter much, but if the gate has two inputs or more, or if it's a combination of logic gates, then the output can do some weird stuff during the transition.

For example, if the input of an AND gate goes from 10 to 01, then **in theory** the output should stay at zero.

If one of the inputs is delayed for a long enough time that the signals have time to transition and the gate has time to react, so that the input signal looks more like 10 then 11 then 10, then the output will have a short logic 1 pulse corresponding to the 11 input, before it returns to zero on the final 10 input.

However, even if the inputs are perfectly in sync, all the transistors in the chip don't match perfectly ; some are slower than others, propagation delays never match perfectly, one input may have a slower risetime than the other, etc.

So, if the input is "10 then 11" in theory, well... in reality it's more like "10 XX 11", or "10 1X 11 X1 01" if one signal is delayed. So, on all the transitions, depending when and how fast they happen, the logic gate may (or not) output voltage that isn't a well defined logic level.

It will eventually settle to the correct value after the guaranteed tpd in the datasheet.

> However, if one input arrives faster than the other input does the output get produced?

So basically, if the time delay between inputs (aka skew) is much longer than the gate's speed, then the answer is yes, it will do what you think. If the skew is a fraction of the gate's speed, it may output a pulse of undefined voltage before settling to the final value.

If it's not a logic gate but a complicated combinatorial circuit like an adder, then that combines circuit that go through various numbers of logic gates, thus different propagation delays. So as signals propagate through it, the outputs will usually flip and wiggle until they settle. This means you cant' trust the output of an adder until it has settled, which is why a there is usually a clocked register (flop) at the output.

> Additionally, is there such thing as a time delay AND gate?

Every logic gate has a propagation delay, so yes.

If you mean something else, like "both inputs have to be 1 for a specific amount of time before the output goes to 1" then no, but you can combine one shots, monostables, and gates to build it. Or you could use down-counters for your delay and output 1 when they both reach zero, plenty of ways to do it.